# How to change wifi band from 2.4 ghz to 5 ghz

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth

I have connected to internet troughout android hotspot on ubuntu laptop and have connected bluetooth earbuds. Problem is that i think becouse wifi and bluetooth work on same frequency that they interfere with each other and thus wifi is ocasionaly turning off and when that happen earbuds sound got bad. I have tried to change wifi frequancy to 5ghz but i cabt find where is that option so i need help how to change wifi band from 2.4 to 5. I have
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. Also i havent this problem on windows 11.

Comment: You can try to open the connections-editor with a right click on the wlan symbol, then you should be able to make a double click on your wlan name, there should be an option `band` and here you can select the 5Ghz band

Comment: In my experience, why I connect my Ubuntu laptops to a 2.4GHz network of course it'll use 2.4Ghz, however the moment I connect to a 5GHz network it's using 5GHz. I have machines that use both, but the Ubuntu laptops just auto-use whatever the wifi-router is requiring.  Connect to a 5GHz network and not a 2.4Ghz network.

Comment: Change the wifi hotspot on the phone to only use 5GHz